# Making small components on runtime

Tags: vue.js, datatables

I am having a problem working with JQuery DataTable. **I had to use that plugin since I had no other choice allowed due to my project requirements.**

So the problem is that, I am adding rows to DataTable and in the row there's a column with button HTML tag. Now I want to bind an on click handler to the button.

```
dt.Rows.Add({
   column_1_data,
   column_2_data,
   "<button @click='itsVueTime'>MyButton</button>"
});
```

Here dt is the DataTable's instance. Now the problem is @click won't work. I understand that its not being rendered by Vue thats why its not working.

Is there a way to bind click event in this condition?

Comment: the `@click` convention is something that gets compiled into the code that vue generates, it you'r putting that into the dom or part of a separate script it's not going to work. You may need to show more code. How are you instantiating the vue component/app?

Comment: Shameless plug, this may help you: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more context, I would recommend this way of doing it

In your component with the method you want to use, you can expose the component like this. (I use mounted, but you can use other lifecycle methods too like `created`)

```js
  mounted() {
    window.app = this;
  }
```

then you can use

```html
<button onclick="app.holler()">Say Hello</button>
```

you can also expose just the function you want to use like so

```js
  mounted() {
    window.itsVueTime = this.itsVueTime;
  }
```